Some mathematician with mental illness who was a friend of Paul Erdős that has some open problems in Combinatorics
I remember a few years ago reading his bio in Wiki page, but I don't remember his name.
I know there's a list of open problems in combinatorics that bear his name. If I remember correctly his problems were concerning Fourier analysis and Combinatorics.
But I may remember it wrongly.
I do remember he was a friend of Paul Erdős.
Does someone know who this may be?

Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Sidon ?

Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Folkman ? (The determination of Folkman numbers)

@GHfromMO yes it is Sidon. I remember quite interesting problems.

sadly, "mental illness" doesn't seem too distinctive

This is too long for a comment. It's already been established that the mathematician being referred to is Simon Sidon. The book "Mathematical Cultures: The London Meetings 2012–2014" attributes the following quote (which is sourced to a video interview) to P. Erdős about Simon Sidon:


… In 1934 I met a Hungarian mathematician called Sidon who worked mostly in trigonometric series.  And he was a very good mathematician, but he was a bit crazier than the average … mathematician ….  In fact he was a bordeline schizophrenic.  They tell about him that he usually talked this way to you (turning away from the audience), he turned towards the wall and talked.  But when he talked about mathematics he talked sense.  And he even made it into a Hungarian anecdote book, because once when in 1937, when Turán and I visited him — he (Sidon) also had a persecution complex — so he opened a door a crack and said ‘Please come at another time and to another person’ … ‘Kérem, jöjjenek inkább máskor és máshoz!’  It sounds better in Hungarian.


I tried to transcribe the quote, but I'm not sure I got the Hungarian correct.  I hope any error can be pardoned and fixed.

@LSpice Fixed it. "ö" and "ő" are two different letters. You use the former in "jöjjenek".

@GHfromMO, re, thanks; it was here on MO, and possibly from you, that I learned that Erdős's name was spelled thus and not as Erdös. In this case I plead not ignorance of the difference between the letters but poor vision that didn't allow me to see the difference.
